# Using German Mac keyboard like a Windows keyboard – circumflex and "less-than" keys are swapped

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac

I am using both a German QWERTZ (full size) Mac and Windows keyboard on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Out of the box, this works nicely – my keyboard layout is set to "German", `keyboard-configuration` uses "Generic 102-key (Intl) PC", and the Mac keyboard behaves like plugged in under Windows.

This is my keyboard layout as shown in GNOME:

[image]

The only problem is that the Mac keyboard's <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>^</kbd> keys are swapped in the OS. In other words, when I press <kbd><</kbd> on the Mac keyboard, I get a dead-key circumflex, and when I press the <kbd>^</kbd> key, I get a "less than" sign. On the Windows keyboard, this works as expected though.

How can I fix this behavior?

Note that I do not want the Mac keyboard to behave like, well, a Mac keyboard in the sense that I want to map <kbd>Cmd</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  or anything fancy. I just want it to behave like under Windows.

Comment: Mac keyboards have a different layout that has to be explicitly selected. And there are several regional German layouts.

Comment: I know that the Mac keyboard has a different layout, and that in principle you can select a Mac layout when configuring the input sources, but that maps `Cmd` to `Ctrl` and the `@`-key is on `L` and not on `Q` like the Windows keyboards do. I am specifically talking about a "normal" DIN 2137-1:2012-06 T1 mapping.